# Simple client-server solution - how to autenthificate users?

Tags: c#, authentication, client-server

Just got a task to create clien-server system (no more specification yet) but I am sure there will be some kind of user login needed. All I can think of now is just DB based login, if the user is a DB user with e.g. read rights, it will let him continue. Is there any other built-in solution suitable for that?

Comment: If a web client is enough then ASP.NET Membership can provide the user management model. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Also have a look at the Client Application Services. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384297.aspx

Answer (score 0):

try to manage users from the application (add a table called users in your DB) don't let users access to DB permissions!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use windows Authentication, or you can authenticate users using NTLM if they your targeted users are located inside the LAN, which is more secure, there is a best practices check the following links 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301240
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/security/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/94612/Windows-Authentication